# how to reserved bar in stacked bar chart for sequential

Tags: highcharts

how to sequential stacked bar chart and example  want the bar chart to start at john and finish at joe

Highcharts.chart('container', {
chart: {
type: 'bar'
},
title: {
text: 'Stacked bar chart'
},
xAxis: {
categories: ['Apples', 'Oranges', 'Pears', 'Grapes', 'Bananas']
},
yAxis: {
min: 0,
title: {
text: 'Total fruit consumption'
}
},
legend: {
reversed: true
},
plotOptions: {
series: {
stacking: 'normal'
}
},
series: [{
name: 'John',
data: [5, 3, 4, 7, 2]
}, {
name: 'Jane',
data: [2, 2, 3, 2, 1]
}, {
name: 'Joe',
data: [3, 4, 4, 2, 5]
}]
});

[example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tiJ9Z.png)

Comment: Is that the output that you want to achieve? https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/bv5m2hps/